# nginx(1.16.1) doesn't respond incoming requests with http2 protcol

Tags: linux, nginx, openssl, centos7, http2

here my setup :
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core), nginx/1.16.1 , OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips

I want to respond all requests to my website using http2 protocol and I already enabled TLS but still respond in http1 format

Also consider : No ALPN negotiated

```
    echo | openssl s_client -alpn h2 -connect mywebsite:443 | grep ALPN
    depth=1 C = PL, O = Unizeto Technologies S.A., OU = Certum Certification Authority, CN = 
    Certum Domain Validation CA SHA2
    verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
    DONE
    No ALPN negotiated
```

and below is my nginx configuration :

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    server_name  www.servername.com;
    root         /path;
    index index.html

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;  
    gzip_static on;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/server.key";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

 location /developer-portal/
    {
            limit_req zone=ip burst=10 nodelay;   
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  'https://severname.com';
            proxy_pass https://IPaddress:443;
    }

    location / {
           # limit_req zone=ip burst=10 nodelay;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: blob: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' data:; frame-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' ; object-src 'none' ";
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;       
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

what is my solution?

Comment: Without more information, this is almost impossible to debug - where did you install nginx from? Was it built against the same version of openssl that's on the box (if it was built against an older version it might only be able to respond to NPN, and not ALPN)? What does `nginx -V` report about openSSL?

Comment: thanx @Petesh
I will reply soon.

Comment: I made a dumb centos container with nginx serving with TLS, and it's negotiating http2 via alpn - https://github.com/anya-evergreen/nginx-centos-h2-alpn. The container can be built, and then run with `docker run -p 443:443 -E SERVERNAME=localhost <name>`.

Comment: thanx @Petesh nginx -V shows it was built with openssl 1.0.2k-fips